# Iterable object and Django StreamingHttpResponse

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I want to connect to internal http services with django and I need to buffer the output the http response of those services because some contents are very large.

I am using python 3.6, django 2.0, `http.client` and the following code:

```python
class HTTPStreamIterAndClose():
    def __init__(self, conn, res, buffsize):
        self.conn = conn
        self.res = res
        self.buffsize = buffsize
        self.length = 1

        bytes_length = int(res.getheader('Content-Length'))

        if buffsize < bytes_length:
            self.length = math.ceil(bytes_length/buffsize)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        buff = self.res.read(self.buffsize)

        if buff is b'':
            self.res.close()
            self.conn.close()

            raise StopIteration
        else:

            return buff

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length


def passthru_http_service(request, server, timeout, path):
    serv = HTTPService(server, timeout)
    res = serv.request(path)

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        HTTPStreamIterAndClose(serv.connection, res, 200),
        content_type='application/json'
    )
    response['Content-Length'] = res.getheader('Content-Length')

    return response
```

And the reponse is empty, I test the iterator with:

```
b''.join(HTTPStreamIterAndClose(serv.connection, res, 200)
```

And everything works fine, I don't know why is not working.

Comment: Are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: No, there's no error

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Do you get http 500? 200 with a blank output? Provide `curl -v http://localhost:8000/x/y/` (or Postman or ...) output in your question please.

Comment: As I say, empty response, nothing =(

Comment: Use an external connection as client, you will be see really "what happened" ! According to your question, it is impossible to connect to a loopback address this way (define another loopback for the stream job).

Comment: That may seem a bit of a long-shot @FelipeBuccioni but can you try and change the `content_type` to `text/event-stream` (or even remove it all together)?

Comment: What WSGI server are you using? Is there a nginx-like proxy in front of it?

Answer (score 4):

https://andrewbrookins.com/django/how-does-djangos-streaminghttpresponse-work-exactly/

> First, some conditions must be true:
>
> - The client must be speaking `HTTP/1.1` or newer
> - The request method wasn’t a `HEAD`
> - The response does not include a `Content-Length` header
> - The response status wasn’t `204` or `304`

> If these conditions are true, then Gunicorn will add a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header to the
> response, signaling to the client that the response will stream in
> chunks.
>
> In fact, Gunicorn will respond with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` even if
> you used an HttpResponse, if those conditions are true!
>
> To really stream a response, that is, to send it to the client in
> pieces, the conditions must be true, and your response needs to be an
> iterable with multiple items.

Basically, you need to decide: streaming or `Content-Length`.

If you want resumable downloads use [`Range`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233).

Comment: Does this apply to other WSGI servers as well?

Comment: IDK, I didn't experiment.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, the problem was in the fact that the http request disconnects after a some ms, thats why when I iterate inmediatly after the connection and before the creation of the objects works find and not when I use after the response, but when I start the connection when start to iterate, all works perfectly =/.

Cheers.